# multiplatform IDE for developing graphical interfaces in C++

Tags: c++, user-interface, ide, cross-platform

I want to start making graphical user interfaces in C++ in some IDE, easy to learn and have enough documentation and examples. Besides being multiplatform, ie the final application can be run on both Linux and Windows

Some suggestions or experiences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend Qt Creator.

The Qt libraries are multiplatform, cover a wide range of features and are well documented; the IDE too runs almost everywhere, is really easy to set up and is very well integrated with the library.

Other open source alternatives may be the wxWidgets with e.g. CodeBlocks, but in my opinion they aren't as good (in terms of completeness and documentation), and you don't have such a good integration with the IDE (also, in my experience setting up wxWidgets development on Windows needs some work).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Eclipse which is open source and works well on Linux/Windows . There is descent documentation available as well..